# If I enable auto-compaction on Cassandra, do I still need to use `nodetool compact`?

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster with a keyspace named `foo` and a table named `y`.

If I run the following command,

```
$ nodetool enableautocompaction foo y
```

do I still have to manually use `nodetool compact` on `foo.y`?

Does `enableautocompaction` enable minor compaction or major compaction? (The [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsEnableAutoCompaction.html) for that command was rather sparse.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It starts enabled unless you explicitly disable it, you shouldn't need it since its more for some special case scenarios and testing.

You also shouldn't run manual compactions with `nodetool compact` unless you are really sure about what you're doing. Once you run it, the sstable created won't be included in normal compactions for a very long time so you end up having to continually manually manage the number of sstables or suffer poor read performance.

Comment: "Once you run it, the sstable created won't be included in normal compactions for a very long time." Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: For Size Tiered Compaction strategy for example it will do a compaction whenever there is (by default) four like sized sstables and merge them.  When you do a forced major compaction you create 1 sstable the size of all your data, which can be huge. If you have months worth of data it could take months again to get even close to enough data to trigger a compaction with that monster sstable. This old sstable would likely become very stale and obsolete, yet frequently giving a positive on the bloom filter so included in your reads.

Comment: There are some edge use cases where this using compact manually works out but you should assume it won't and only go down that road with significant testing and research.